# font-size: Convert docx into pdf in ruby using WickedPdf and docx

Tags: ruby, docx, wicked-pdf

I'm currently trying to convert a word document into HTML using the [WickedPdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) and [docx](https://github.com/chrahunt/docx) gems. By using the two gems I have been able to convert the Word Document into PDF but the outcome is not what I expected.
[image]

From the attached image you can see the difference from the original word document to the one generated by converting the word document into HTML and then into PDF.

```
 doc = Docx::Document.open('testing.docx') 
 pdf << WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(doc.to_html) # or to_s
 File.open("testing.pdf", 'wb') do |f|
   f << pdf
 end
```

When using `to_html` I get the results as shown in the image below.
[image]

How can I format this so the outcome is better? Are there any suggestions on how to use WickedPDF?

I would like to use the HTML format to convert into PDF to be able to read elements such as tables.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `WickedPdf` but with `prawn` you have to convert each XML node to a format it understands so styles are applied properly.

Comment: You can remove "\n" symbols by doc.to_html.gsub('\n','').

Also, looks like WickedPDF doesn't load default settings. So write something like 
WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(doc.to_html.gsub('\n',''), {orientation: 'Portrait', page_size: 'A4'}). All options you can find on gem's github page

Comment: Any way you could link us to the `testing.docx` file?

Comment: @Unixmonkey Here is a link to the file. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f1klwguv4r9iyje/testing.docx?dl=0

Comment: I got this result https://www.dropbox.com/s/0av6ay96245j1hl/testing.pdf?dl=0 for: doc = Docx::Document.open('testing.docx'); File.open("testing.pdf", 'wb'){|f| f<< WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(doc.to_html.gsub('\n','')) }
Also, docx doesn't parse font color.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the `docx` gem is doing a very good job of converting to HTML for this purpose. You can get content, and font sizing, but not enough structure or styling to recreate your source document. You might want to look into alternatives.